# Build docker images without exposing secrets to the registry

Tags: docker, jenkins, composer-php, continuous-deployment

**What works:**
I do have a `php-fpm` docker container hosting an PHP application that is using composer for managing dependencies. Jenkins builds the container, what also runs `composer install` and pushes it to the registry.

**What should work:**
I want to include a private package from git with composer, what requires authentication. Therefore the container has to be in posses of secrets that should not be leaked to the container registry.

**How can I install composer packages from private repositories without exposing the secrets to the registry?**

**What wont work:**

- let Jenkins run `composer install`. It is necessary for the dev environment to have the dependencies installing while building.
- copy in and out the ssh key during build as that would save it to the layers.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there might be better solutions out there, mine was to use [docker multi stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to have the build process in an early layer that is not included in the final image. That way the container registry never sees the secrets. To verify that I used [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive).

Please see the `Dockerfile` below

```
FROM php-fpm
COPY ./id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/getcomposer.org/76a7060ccb93902cd7576b67264ad91c8a2700e2/web/installer -O - -q | php -- --quiet
COPY ./src /var/www/html
RUN composer install

FROM php-fpm
COPY --from=0 /var/www/html/vendor /var/www/html/vendor
```